# My APK file just to be a common file

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I have a problem, I success to export my file to be APK file. But the problem is the output. There is no apk file, only file with file extention

Please share the solution, this is about my final project :). Thank you

Comment: A file with exactly what extension?  ".apk" is the extension you should be seeing.

Comment: The type of my file is FILE, not APK File. :)

Comment: Your computer probably doesn't have apk files registered as a "type" of file it knows what to do with.  Little secret - they are backwards (but not, due to needed alignment fully forwards) compatible with zip file tools.

Comment: You may also need to change something in you file browser's setting to get raw file extensions to display.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your file does not have the right extension?

Make sure to include the extension (.apk) when exporting the signed apk! :)

Comment: i try to add APK extension, but it can't be installed :(